# Is it ok to use JSON in order to store data in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I would like to store values for each specification of an item, but with the ability to add new specifications through time without modifying my database structure.

That is to have a PHP array in the end that would look something like :

```
$vase['features'] = array('weight'=>10,'height'=>100);
```

But who could very well have fifty keys in a few days.

```
$vase['features'] = array('weight'=>10,'height'=>100,'price'=>12,'time'=>1821,...);
```

I would normally just add a table in my database, but I really don't think adding dozens of columns would do it.

I wonder if it is ok to add a column 'specifications' in which I would store a JSON array? I mean, I am pretty sure it would do the trick, but is there any reason I shouldn't do that or any best solution?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) Though, it will still be hard, but slightly less hard, to filter your results, if set up properly. I want to add that it is called an `anti-pattern`. And that I have only a little experience but was damn glad I found another solution.

Comment: I should have added this directly: I thought long and hard about the entities I had to store, and managed to group them and created tables for those groups. I wrote some PHP to lazy-load the 'extended object' alongside the 'main object' and access it's properties through the main object (no `$main->sub->property`). My luck though was that the 'subobjects' never had to be mixed and shown ordered by some property which was only on one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are fields you don't need to access directly from the database, nor do you need to filter by them (you need to be very sure about this) then it would be ok. As you said, it **will** work, but it really depends on the particulars of your project.

For instance **price** may be problematic, since you will probably want to be able to filter by price with ease (not saying you can't, but it will not be as straight forward as with tables).

The way I would do it is the following:

- A table with a list of features that you can expand with ease
- A table which contains the id of the content (or product) the id of the feature, and the value of the feature.

With that little adaptation you can easily list features, filter by features, group by them etc, and still have the ability to *define* the structure of the products later.

Comment: You describe [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: I thought about that, that is actually similar to something I use in order to store sub-forums' access authorizations. I was wondering, though, if that was not a bit "dangerous"... I have to admit that I don't know much about data storage, though this could result in thousands of entries pretty quickly... I mean, there surely will be enough space, but won't this produce an important delay in mySQL queries?

Comment: Oh it will. Imagine a world where you store strings, integers, floats, booleans and texts, and you had to order it all by value?

Comment: No solution is perfect for a generic scenario. Every scenario has its perfect (or its most desirable) solution. I'm just trying to point you to a possibility that you may or may not have thought of.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the exact number of columns in your database table then it is good idea to store dat in JSON array.Be sure you don't need these data in any order by ,group by, count etc in queries

Answer (score 0):

A question you could ask yourself is: do you need to operate with SQL on your values like select, filter, join etc ? If yes, you couldn't use a json object or serialized php and should create another table.